# How to use level 3 neo characters "`" and "&" in VSCode on MacOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to program in VSCode using the Neo keyboard layout in MacOS.

Here are my Karabiner Elements Rules:

- Neo2 mod 3 key and layer 4 (Apple keyboards)
- Neo2 layer 6
- Toggle caps_lock by pressing left_shift + right_shift at the same time
- Change Command+Tab to Control+Tab
- Change Control+Tab to Command+Tab

With this all level 3 combinations work in VSCode except "`" and "&". In other programs these two characters also appear normally.

How can I get VSCode to write ` and &?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the two characters do not work is that they are being overridden by VSCode's own keyboard shortcuts:

- 3rd layer + q (&): this is the shortcut for "Rewrap Comment / Text".
- 3rd layer + z (`): this is the shortcut for "toggleWordWrap".

The shortcuts prevent the Neo characters from appearing.

To solve the problem simply change the shortcuts for the two commands to not be identical with the 3rd layer characters.

You can find the problematic shortcuts simply by opening the GUI of the Keyboard Shortcuts and clicking on the keyboard and then press your 3rd level combination. Then you can choose new shortcuts or disable the shortcuts.